# Conflict between endfloat and figure floats included via macro

Tags: macros, floats, endfloat

I use `\newcommand` to quickly include figures. But combined with `endfloat`, it throws an error. Any ideas how to send floats to end when included this way?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{endfloat}  % this causes an error

\newcommand{\addfig}[1]{ 
\begin{figure}[htbp]  % when float environment is included here
\centering 
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#1}  
\end{figure} 
} 

\begin{document}
\addfig{fig1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I won't work. See the documentation "10.6. environments names"

Comment: 10.6 of which documentation? thanks

Comment: The documentation of endnotes.

Comment: I see, 10.3 of endfloats. The literal figure environment name must be included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you cannot, as far as I can tell, configure `endfloat` to recognise the command `\addfig` appropriately, you can configure it to recognise additional floating environments such as `addfig`.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newenvironment{addfig}[1]{%
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#1}
}{\end{figure}}
\usepackage{endfloat}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{addfig}{figure}

\begin{document}
\begin{addfig}{example-image-a}
\end{addfig}
\end{document}
```

[image: delayed custom float type]

Comment: works perfect even when I modified `addfig` environment to include a minipage.

Comment: @selig Glad it helped!

Comment: The markup would be a lot nicer if you could do `\addfig{example-image-a}` and not `\begin{addfig}{example-image-a}
\end{addfig}`

Comment: @cfr Why are you putting `\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{addfig}{figure}` inside `endnotes.cfg` instead of applying it directly right after `\usepackage{endnotes}`?

Comment: @StrongBad But this won't be possible without patching the `endfloat` package by using a lot of internals of it. And this will result in ugly stuff without a warranty that it will still work using future versions of the `endfloat` package.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt perhaps (or maybe an expl3 solution), but that is why I offered a bounty.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt I don't remember but the `endfloat` facility I'm using is covered as an option for inclusion in `endfloat.cfg` in the package's documentation. (All of the macros in section 8 are presented in the context of specifying custom options etc. in `endfloat.cfg`.)

Comment: @StrongBad It is pointless to offer the bounty with the current description because you just can't enable `endfloat` to use a macro. I'd suggest rethinking exactly what your requirements are. (Must it be `endfloat` for example? As currently stated, that's a requirement for the bounty. But as people have explained, that can't be done. Of course, you could essentially rewrite everything in the package, but that would just be misleading.)

Comment: @cfr I think this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314129/10038) provides one way of doing it with external files. I think expl3 can handle verbatim arguments in macros, so maybe there is a way there. Maybe there is a simple patch to the package, although the maintainer says no.

Comment: @cfr I think this part of the documentation is misleading. Any endfloat-related code can be either placed in the document after loading the `endfloat` package or within the configuration file. (I guess I should have made this more clear when adding `\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor` to the documentation.) And in fact when testing `\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor` after implementation I never have used configuration files ;-)

Comment: @StrongBad I think Werner's solution is neat. I didn't realise you were happy with that kind of solution, but the idea is a good one. I think you should consider that a solution. I don't think you really need `endfloat` in that case, though. You could just read the file back at the end of the document.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Thanks. I've simplified the code accordingly.

Comment: @StrongBad No, I'm not the maintainer of the `endfloat` package. (But I have build-in some stuff with permission of the maintainer.)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach that writes each figure used in the command form `\addfig[<opts>]{<image>}` to a file `tmpfig.tex` and then immediately reads in that file:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,newfile,endfloat}

\newoutputstream{tmpimg}

\newcommand{\addfig}[2][width=\textwidth]{%
  \openoutputfile{tmpfig.tex}{tmpimg}% Open tmpfig.tex for (over)writing
  % Add figure environment...
  \addtostream{tmpimg}{\protect\begin{figure}[htbp]}
  \addtostream{tmpimg}{\protect\centering}
  \addtostream{tmpimg}{\protect\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}
  \addtostream{tmpimg}{\protect\end{figure}}
  \closeoutputstream{tmpimg}% Close tmpfig.tex
  \input{tmpfig}% Input tmpfig.tex
}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\begin{figure}[htbp]  % when float environment is included here
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure} 

\addfig{example-image-b}

\addfig[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-c}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great Idea!   (This is just some stuff to make this comment at least 15 characters in length ;-))

Comment: This is very neat.

Answer (score 3):

Last but not least a solution which tries to patch the `endfloat` package as less as possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newcommand{\addfig}[1]{%
\begin{figure}[htbp]  % when float environment is included here
\centering 
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#1}  
\end{figure} 
} 

\usepackage{endfloat}[2011/12/25] % we need at least v2.5d
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Adapt \addfig to the endfloat package
% First of all we make \addfig known to the endfloat package as variant of the figure environment
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour{addfig}{figure}
\makeatletter
% Special variant of \efloat@xfloat for commands (instead of environments):
% This macro will be expanded with every line read until \efloat@found@end is used.
% The original version tests if #2 (the actual line read) is "\end{}",
% and uses \efloat@iwrite in case of no and \efloat@found@end in case of yes.
% Our version just writes the line (containing the command and the rest of the line)
% using \efloat@iwrite and finishes the verbatim reading using \efloat@found@end afterwards.
{\catcode`\^^M=12 \endlinechar=-1 %
 \long\gdef\my@efloat@xfloat#1#2^^M{%
  \efloat@iwrite{#1}{#2}% write 1st line (containing the command)...
  \efloat@found@end{#1}%  ...and end verbatim reading afterwards
  \next}}              %  process next line
% Since \addfig is a command and not an environment we need to start a group for our own
% using \begingroup, so it behaves like we would have written \begin{addfig}.
% (Note: The endfloat package is designed to work with environments, not with commands.)
% Additionally we patch \efloat@xfloat to use our own variant of it for this command.
\pretocmd\addfig{%
  \begingroup
  \let\efloat@xfloat\my@efloat@xfloat}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\addfig{example-image}
\end{document}
```

But this solution has two caveats:

1. Everything written in the same line after usage of the command will be written to the file containing the floating environments as well. So it's not possible to write `\addfig{example-image} Some text...` in one line since otherwise "Some text..." would be delayed, too.
2. The command and its arguments must be written in the same line. So it's not possible to split its usage to more lines, e.g. `\addfig{%` as 1st and `example-image}` as 2nd line.

In total we are using the three internal commands `\efloat@xfloat`, `\efloat@iwrite`, and `\efloat@float@end` here.

**Addendum 2018-03-25**

Since endfloat v2.6 things get a little easier since the test "is this the last line of the environment" is now available as `\efloat@if@end`, so this is the only internal command we need to patch:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newcommand{\addfig}[1]{%
\begin{figure}[htbp]  % when float environment is included here
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#1}
\end{figure}
}

\usepackage{endfloat}[2018/01/01] % we need at least v2.6
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Adapt \addfig to the endfloat package
% First of all we make \addfig known to the endfloat package as variant of the figure environment
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavour{addfig}{figure}
\makeatletter
% Since \addfig is a command and not an environment we need to start a group for our own
% using \begingroup, so it behaves like we would have written \begin{addfig}.
% (Note: The endfloat package is designed to work with environments, not with commands.)
% Additionally we patch \efloat@if@end (usually expanding to \@firstoftwo or \@secondoftwo)
% so the very first command line will be written to the file and the verbatim reading will be
% finished afterwards.
\newcommand\my@efloat@if@end[3]{#3#2}
\pretocmd\addfig{%
  \begingroup
  \let\efloat@if@end\my@efloat@if@end}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\addfig{example-image}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution based on [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314129/) but which does away with the use of `endfloat` altogether. Once we are writing the figures to an external file anyhow, there doesn't seem much need for `endfloat` as we can just read the figures in from the file at the end of the document.

It happens to use the `expl3` syntax, but that is really by-the-by. `expl3` doesn't buy you anything special here - it is just an alternative syntax.

There is one macro:

```
\addfig[<options>]{<filename>}{<caption>}
```

Obviously, the optional argument is for options to be passed to `\includegraphics`, the second argument is for the name of the image file and the third is for the caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xparse,kantlipsum}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtBeginDocument
{
  \iow_new:N \l_strongbad_addfigs_stream
  \iow_open:Nn \l_strongbad_addfigs_stream { \jobname.addfigs }
}
\AtEndDocument
{
  \iow_close:N \l_strongbad_addfigs_stream
  \listoffigures
  \file_input:n { \jobname.addfigs }
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \strongbad_addfig:nnn
{
  \group_begin:
  \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str { \setcounter{figure} }
  \str_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_str { \c_left_brace_str }
  \str_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_str { \thefigure }
  \str_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_str { \c_right_brace_str }
  \iow_now:Nx \l_strongbad_addfigs_stream { \l_tmpa_str }
  \iow_now:Nn \l_strongbad_addfigs_stream
  {
    \begin{ figure }
      \centering
      \includegraphics [ #1 ] { #2 }
      \caption { #3 }
    \end{ figure }
  }
  \stepcounter{figure}
  \skip_vertical:N \bigskipamount
  \centering
  [~\figurename{}~\thefigure{}~about~here~]
  \skip_vertical:N \bigskipamount
  \group_end:
}
\NewDocumentCommand \addfig { O {} m +m }
{
  \strongbad_addfig:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\addfig{example-image-a}{first end figure}
\kant[2]
\addfig  {example-image-b}{second end figure}
\kant[3]
\addfig [width=.25\textwidth] {tiger} {third end figure}
\kant[4-5]
\end{document}
```

[image: floats to end without <code>endfloat</code>]

Comment: This is very nice, but `endfloat` is still useful in the case where you only use `\addfig` some of the time.

Comment: @StrongBad Yes, but you already have Werner's answer for that. No point in reinventing the wheel. What I like about this is that you can send some figures to the end without sending all of them. (I don't know `endfloat` so maybe it provides that functionality as well.)

Comment: I just don't know how the numbering should go in that case.